# How this code works - regarding union initialization in c?

Tags: c, initialization, unions

I got the output 0 2 for this program.....
but don't know  why?
Please explain i think only int i is initialized with 512.
*But how ch[1] got the value 2.*

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    union a /* declared */
    {
        int i;   char ch[2];
    };
    union a z = { 512 };   

    printf("%d%d", z.ch[0], z.ch[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Union declaration means that all its members are allocated the same memory. So your `int i` and `char ch[2]` are referencing the same memory space -- in other words, they are aliased. Whenever you change one, you will change the other as well.

Now, assuming your `int`s are 32-bit wide and you're on a little-endian system like x86, `i = 512` (512 == 0x00000200) actually looks like this in memory:

```
0x00  0x02  0x00  0x00.
```

with the first two values corresponding directly to the 2-character array:

```
ch[0] ch[1]
```

So you get `ch[0] == 0x0` and `ch[1] == 0x02`.

Try setting your `i = 0x1234` and see what effect it will have on your character array.

Based on your question, it's possible that you may want to use a `struct` instead of `union` -- then its members would be allocated in memory sequentially (one after the other).

Comment: This is the real answer, the only answer which mentions what a union is.

Comment: sidyll: the question was not what a union is, besides there are already a lot of questions regarding that topic. it is a good answer though :)

Comment: @pivotnig +1, and anyways, it doesn't mean that OP should downvote every other answer!!

Answer (score 3):

512 is 0x200 in hex, so the first byte of your union is 0 the second is 2. If you dont specify which union member should be initialized, the first one will be taken, the `int` in your case.

You get 2 for the second byte of your string as the first byte of `ch` is intialized with 0, the second one with 2.

Comment: i cant understand.int is the first union member.it should be initialized..why the char array gets initialized

Comment: Intel processors (well, x86 at least) store integers backwards; the least significant byte has the lowest address. For a 32-bit value, 0x01020304 would be stored in memory as 0x04030201. Likewise, 512 is 0x00000200, and is stored in memory as 0x00020000. This lines up with `char[0]` as 0 and `char[1]` as 2.

Comment: refer me some helpful links...pls

Comment: Actually this is UB. The char array doesn't have to be initialized.

Comment: @cdummy If you don't know what a `union` is, how did you write the code? Don't you have the resource in front of you?

Comment: If I enter "C union" in my favorite search engine I immediately find a lot of information. What do you think this is, here?

Answer (score 1):

Simple: 512 = binary 1000000000, so ch[0] will get the 8 zeroes (assuming your system is little endian) and ch[1] will get the 10 part, which, in decimal, is 2.

Comment: Why on Earth are you downvoting this?

Answer (score 1):

you intermix 'struct' with 'union'. in union you collect different typed and named data into one field (with lenght = maximum (size of data)), which you can access, and for which you have yourself make sure you get the right data.

your example allocs memory for max(int, char[2])
It is no difference, if you say z.i = 32 or z.ch[0]=' '

Answer (score 0):

You got `0 2` for good reasons but the C standard says that the behavior is not defined. If you write `i` then the value of `ch` can be theoretically anything.

However, the gcc assures that the data will be well-aligned.